# List the size of subdirectories only considering pdf files

Tags: disk-usage

I've tried to list the size of subdirectories of the directory home just taking the files with pdf extension.

I tried the next

```
ls $home -d /* | xargs du -sb --exclude="!(*.pdf)"
```

Is there any `--include` option for `du`? or what should be the right pattern in the exclude option?

Answer (score 2):

```
find ~ -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec du -sh {} \;
```

`-exec`  runs programs being you mentioned via `{}` , Indeed you say to `find command` such as:

```
du -sh   *.pdf
```

`-type` specifiy type of file , `f` mentioned to `regular file`.

And `~` mentioned to path base path of search.

`-iname`  mentioned to Incasentisive search.

Comment: You have been around long enough to know that posting a solitary command is not often considered the most helpful thing to do. Consider expanding your post with some explanation or links to helpful resources that support your solution.